# Redireccionar desde java script, dentro de un Json Succces

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de validar el inicio de sesión de mi aplicación con un método `POST`, pero el problema es que no sé cómo redireccionar un vez que obtengo la respuesta desde el servidor.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("IniciarSesion", "Inicio")',
    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "Usuario": _usuario, "Clave": _clave },
    success: function (respuesta) {

        if (respuesta.model == '1') {

            //aqui debería redireccionar de alguna manera

        } else if (respuesta.model == '0')
        {
            Alert.render('El usuario ingresado no está registrado');

        } else if (respuesta.model == '2') {

            Alert.render('La clave ingresada es incorrecta');
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Alert.render('Error: No se pudo cargar método "Validar Usuario"');
    }
});
```

Lo trabajo de esta manera, ya que necesito indicar información de errores de ingreso. Por eso no utilizo el submit.

Comment: usa location.href = "tupagina.html"

Comment: hola, gracias pero location.href = "tupagina.html" no he esta funcionando

Comment: location.href = "Home/Inicio/"; pasa por el controlador al metodo Resirect.. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo location.href = "https://www.google.com/"; ó location.href = "tupagina.html" sirve, hay que considerar, lo siguiente: location.href = "Controller/ActionResult";

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("IniciarSesion", "Inicio")',
                    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { "Usuario": _usuario, "Clave": _clave },
                    success: function (respuesta) {

                        if (respuesta.model == '1') {
                            location.href = "Home/Inicio/";
                        } else if (respuesta.model == '0')
                        {
                            Alert.render('El usuario ingresado no está registrado');
                        } else if (respuesta.model == '2') {
                            Alert.render('La clave ingresada es incorrecta');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        Alert.render('Error: No se pudo cargar método "Validar Usuario"');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

Añadir la siguiente línea en la parde donde quieres redirigir:

```
window.location.href = "urlaredireccionar.html";
```

Accedes a `window` y rediriges a otra `window` con la url deseada.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("IniciarSesion", "Inicio")',
    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "Usuario": _usuario, "Clave": _clave },

}).done(function (respuesta){
   if (respuesta.model == '1') {
            //aqui debería redireccionar de alguna manera
            window.location.href = "urlaredireccionar.html";

        } else if (respuesta.model == '0')
        {
            Alert.render('El usuario ingresado no está registrado');

        } else if (respuesta.model == '2') {

            Alert.render('La clave ingresada es incorrecta');
        }
}).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    Alert.render('Error: No se pudo cargar método "Validar Usuario"');
});
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Con las nuevas versiones de jQuery algunas cosas quedaron obsoletas como lo son
 `success, error y complete`
Ahora se debe usar `.done, .fail, .always`

Por ahora con navegadores como Chrome y firefox no encontrarás problemas pero si intentas ejecutar tu código en internet explorer es más probable que encuentres problemas o que tu script falle y no sepas que pasó sin ver la consola.

Comment: Hola @Mariano gracias por pensar en ello, ya modifique mi pregunta explicando lo que hice, actualmente no conozco otra alternativa pero si la llego a encontrar la agregaré, te agradezco tu interes. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href = "https://www.google.com/";
```

Cambia google por la pagina que quieras direccionamiento.

Comment: hola, gracias pero location.href = "tupagina.html" no he esta funcionando

Comment: location.href = "Home/Inicio/"; pasa por el controlador al metodo Resirect.. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Veo que no te es útil location.href inténtalo de ésta forma

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: muchas gracis, location.href si sirve pero, el valor que se debe entregar varia en mvc